# Is BODMAS(order of operations) more than just a convention?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

I was wondering about BODMAS and searched a bit on google and found that it was a convention which was adopted to avoid *inconsistency* in answers. If it was just a convention, there could have been possibilities that addition or subtraction were given more priority than multiplication or division and so it would have affected today's math and physics etc... But perhaps *luckily* this convention turned out to be good(if consider today's math satisfactorily developed). So now my question is that if this convention had been like(for example) Addition then multiplication, would it turn out good? Would it work?

Comment: What does it mean ? That in "using" number to describe operations with reality, we are driven by reality. In order to describe it correctly, we have to use parentheses. Convention are **useful** to save ink, not to generate the sixth egg from nothing.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i am not asking to interchange the operations, i am asking about the _order_ of them

Comment: Again, consider $3 \times 2 +1$: When you write it, are you describing two sets of 3 eggs each plus one egg, or are you describing 3 sets of 2+1=3 eggs ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you, i got it

Answer (score 1):

It is *just* a convention, but it was chosen to be as convenient as possible for the way we do math. That's all it is.

Comment: My question is if there would be a different convention,what would have happened?

Comment: @Pj30 A lot more parentheses and much lower readability. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Pj30 Remember when the internet argued about $8\div2(2+2)$? That's what happens when some people follow PEMDAS instead.

Comment: @J.G. No, that's what happens when people think the order of operations is unambiguous, but can't agree what the resolution is. Which makes it, by definition, ambiguous.

Comment: @Arthur Or to unite our descriptions, it's what happens when each is taught in different schools and their former students don't realize the other option exists, and they argue on a forum where nobody points out it's purely semantic.